# Angular 8 doesn't wait until the new value is rendered on the view

Tags: angular, printing

I'm trying to print a document using window.print() but angular doesn't wait until the new value is rendered. It keeps printing the old value.

I'm trying to print right after assigning the new value to the object like this

```
obj1.attr1 = "new value"
window.print()
```

The browser keeps printing the old value. How to print the new value instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a timeout with a small value.

```
setTimeout(() => window.print());
```

Comment: It worked like a charm on firefox and chrome! Thank you!

Comment: @user3768828 - This is more of a hackish way to fix the issue. I would suggest you force change detection manually instead.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that once you update the value, it will not reflect in the view until the next change detection cycle completes, which will be after the print is executed. You can use `setTimeout` to fix this but that would be more of a hack IMO.

Instead, you can use `detectChanges` to force the change detection manually. This way the new value will reflect on the view and only then will the print be executed.

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

// ...

obj1.attr1 = "new value";
this.cd.detectChanges();
window.print();
```

Comment: This feels way less hacky than setting a timeout. This ensures that the change detection hook is run and the view is updated regardless of how long it takes to get the data and render it, the load and following print will be correctly sequentially run.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rxjs-operator `observe` that can be used to observe changes with a certain object:

```js
import { observe } from "rxjs-observe";
// ...
const obj1 = { attr1: "init" };
const { observables, proxy } = observe(obj1);

// when attr1 of obj1 changed then window.print is called
observables.attr1.subscribe(() => window.print());
// ...
// assign a new value to the property of obj1
proxy.attr1 = "new value";
```

This `observe` operation can be found [here](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-observe/blob/master/README.md)